# swiftUI rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: swiftui

I'm make this game to learn about Swift, but am having some issues with it. This error appears:

> `(LocalizedStringKey) -> Text` is not convertible to
>   `(LocalizedStringKey, String?, Bundle?, StaticString?) -> Text`

```swift
        VStack(spacing: 30){
            Text("Continue") 
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.black)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible kind of error. Of course, nothing is wrong with that TextView: the problem is somewhere else. But Xcode isn't able (yet) to find the real error. So please make sure that you use the newest version of Xcode.

You will have to comment out the code piece by piece, and then find out what line gives the real problem.

If you need help with that, please also post the code that is around the fragment you posted.